# Summary() not showing some level of data in R

Tags: r, summary, hmisc

Just came across HMISC summary() which looks like a quick tool for preparing shell tables for descriptive stats for my manuscripts.

I have this code :

```
summary.stats<-summary(lead_ind ~ age + gender + Region,  npct="both", method="reverse",data=DfStudy, test=TRUE)
> str(DfStudy$gender)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
> str(DfStudy$lead_ind)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "<5","> 5": NA 1 1 1 1 NA 1 1 2 2 ...
> str(DfStudy$Region)
 Factor w/ 11 levels "ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)         ",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

However, my results table has only one level for gender.

```
---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                                       |N   |<5                        |> 5                       |  Test                         |
|                                       |    |(N=1147)                  |(N=145)                   |Statistic                      |
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|age                                    |1705|       4.445/ 8.530/12.910|       3.310/ 6.550/10.760|  F=13.15 d.f.=1,1290 P<0.001  |
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|gender : Male                          |1705|           49% (565)      |           66% ( 95)      |Chi-square=13.62 d.f.=1 P<0.001|
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|Region : ASIA (EX. NEAR EAST)          |1705|           37% (422)      |           67% ( 97)      |Chi-square=49.91 d.f.=4 P<0.001|
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|    BALTICS                            |    |            0% (  0)      |            0% (  0)      |                               |
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|    C.W. OF IND. STATES                |    |            0% (  2)      |            0% (  0)      |                               |
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|    EASTERN EUROPE                     |    |            0% (  0)      |            0% (  0)      |                               |
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|    LATIN AMER. & CARIB                |    |           20% (235)      |            9% ( 13)      |                               |
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|    NEAR EAST                          |    |            7% ( 80)      |            2% (  3)      |                               |
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|    NORTHERN AFRICA                    |    |            0% (  0)      |            0% (  0)      |                               |
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|    NORTHERN AMERICA                   |    |            0% (  0)      |            0% (  0)      |                               |
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|    OCEANIA                            |    |            0% (  0)      |            0% (  0)      |                               |
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|    SUB-SAHARAN AFRICA                 |    |           36% (408)      |           22% ( 32)      |                               |
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
|    WESTERN EUROPE                     |    |            0% (  0)      |            0% (  0)      |                               |
+---------------------------------------+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
>
```

Comment: Do you really need the level for female? Since your gender variable is binary, the n (%) of female is implied from the n (%)s of the male, no? Unless you have missing gender I guess.